# Is it natural and meaningful to use the verb "conceive" in the following text?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning

> Well-fed people are **conceived of** being more healthy physically and mentally. However, the incidence of cancer and psychological problems in wealthy countries are relatively higher than in poor countries. In fact, this is just the ratio of water-borne and food-borne diseases that correlates with nutrition.

In the first sentence I want to say that this is just a conventional wisdom and is not based on empirical evidence. Did I choose a correct word?

Comment: You'd be better off with "usually thought of as" or something similar. Also, I'm not sure your logic is sound here either. Compare average life expectancy between the two kinds of countries, and developed nations are far ahead.

Comment: Well-fed sounds like chickens or cows. [is relatively higher]. People are not generally said to be well-fed in the sense of people who get proper nutrition or enough food to live normally.

Comment: I'd say "conceived of as being", but the other suggestions are good.